# Given an integer, represent it as s sum of squares

Tags: c++, algorithm, root, square

If I have number **75**, my output should look like:
`64+9+1+1`

I have tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int number, sum = 0;
  cin >> number;

  for (int i = number; i > 0; i--) {
    if (sqrt(i) == round(sqrt(i))) {
      if (number-i > 1) {
        cout << i << "+";
        number -= i;
        sum += i;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = number; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i == 1) {
      cout << "+1";
    } else {
      cout << "1";
    }
  }
}
```

With input **75** code works properly, but if I enter **24**, then I should receive:

```
This: 16+4+4
However I get: 16+4+1+11+1
```

If I type **1245**

I receive this: `1225+16+1+11+1`

However correct answer is: `1225+16+4`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 5 cents here. The idea is to find the closest square root which power of 2 is less or equal to the given number. Write down this square number and then subtract it from the number. Repeat the procedure if the number is still greater than `0` (I assume `number` is a positive integer number):

```
void main() {
    uint32_t number;
    cin >> number;

    while (number > 0) {
        uint32_t floorRoot = floor(sqrt(number));
        uint32_t squareNumber = floorRoot * floorRoot;

        cout << squareNumber;
        number -= squareNumber;

        if (number > 0) {
            cout << "+";
        }
    }
}
```

**Example usage**

> Input: 67
>
> Output: 64+1+1+1

**UPDATE:**

If `number` is any integer then the code could be improved as follows:

```
void main() {
    int number;
    cin >> number;

    // abs(INT_MIN) is still negative!!!
    if (number == INT_MIN) {
        printf("Please provide a number larger than %i", INT_MIN);
        return;
    }

    if (!number) {
        cout << "0";
        return;
    }

    while (number != 0) {
        int floorRoot = floor(sqrt(abs(number)));
        int squareNumber = floorRoot * floorRoot;

        if (number > 0) {
            cout << squareNumber;
            number -= squareNumber;
        } else {
            cout << -squareNumber;
            number += squareNumber;
        }

        if (number > 0) {
            cout << "+";
        }
    }
}
```

**Example usages**

> Input: -67
>
> Output: -64-1-1-1
>
> Input: 67
>
> Output: 64+1+1+1
>
> Input: 0
>
> Output: 0

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first rewrite the algorithm.

1) Start iterating from `sqrt(number)`, not from number, down to 1, treat the `i` as a root (i.e. square it). It should be a lot faster.

2) To check that a `+` char is needed it is better to have a bool flag that represents that something has already been written to the output and write a `+` *before* a square number based on that flag.

I think the problem with your algorithm is that you check every square at most once, while it may appear more than once.